# Updating links that are set to Manual in PPT with C#

Tags: c#

I have a monthly deliverable that involves updating an excel file and and a powerpoint with objects that link to said file.

I have written some C# to open the excel file and refresh the connections easily enough, but the powerpoint is giving me difficulty. Specifically, I want the powerpoint updates to be manual on a regular basis, but the presentation.updatelinks() doesn't seem to work unless the links are set to automatically update when the file is opened.

My current code looks something like:

```
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
```

...

then

```
public void Main()
    {
        PowerPoint.Application ppt = new PowerPoint.Application();
        PowerPoint.Presentation PRS = ppt.Presentations.Open(Filename.pptx",
        Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);


        PRS.UpdateLinks();
        PRS.Save()
ppt.quit();
```

I was curious about using perhaps some PowerPoint.LinkFormat... functionality, but I must be missing a reference or something because the only option I have when I type linkformat is linkformat.equals(...)

So I guess there are 2 possible answers to my question:

1. how to updatelinks when the links are set to manual within a presentation
2. How to Change them to automatic, update, then change them back.

I have looked everywhere online and still can't find an answer, but here's to hoping you guys can help.

Thanks so much

Comment: does bumping work on this site? lets find out